# Heroku: bash: bundle: command not found

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.2, cedar

My heroku deployment is crashing with following errors.

```
2012-12-12T17:16:18+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bundle: command not found
2012-12-12T17:16:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2012-12-12T17:16:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

The Heroku documentation for this error is to set PATH and GEM variables as described in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/changing-ruby-version-breaks-path I tried that, however that too is not helping.

```
→ heroku config:add PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
→ heroku config:add GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
→ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.7130
bash: bundle: command not found
```

**Next, I tried setting Ruby version in my Heroku app. This increased the slugsize. But app was still not up.**

Gemfile

```
ruby "1.9.2"
```

Pushed to Heroku

```
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.2
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.2
```

heroku run "ruby -v"

```
Running `ruby -v` attached to terminal... up, run.4483
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]
```

Can someone please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your path is incorrect.

1. If you're trying to use Ruby 1.9.3 you don't need to do anything,
   it's the default Ruby so you can remove those config vars.
2. If you're using
   1.8.7 or 1.9.2, then upgrade to 1.9.3 as it's current.
3. If you're looking at using Ruby 2.0.0.p3 - you're on your own ;)

Comment: Thank you Neil for the response. Locally I am using 1.9.2. The Heroku settings for 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 seem to be the same GEM_PATH: vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1 PATH: bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
Check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/changing-ruby-version-breaks-path

Comment: remove the PATH and GEM_PATH config vars and try that, you shouldn't need them

Comment: I had /vendor/bundle in my slugignore for some reason. That caused the problem.

Comment: Sorry to bash in on an old question, but has anyone found a solution for projects running ruby 2.0.0 or higher and get the same problem?